Erasing EMMC using dd commands in linux
I would like to erase the contents (or at least the boot area) of EMMC in which there is a linux installation. It was suggested that I could use the following sequence of commands to achieve this:
$ sudo dd dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0boot0 bs=1M status=noxfer
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0boot1 bs=1M status=noxfer
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M status=noxfer
$ sync

Given that these are themselves linux command will I be able to run all 4 or will the linux installation stall after putting in the first line?
With no proper linux installed in EMMC I would then be able to run another OS from SDcard.

Why not just install Linux on the EMMC? Virtually all Linux installers have an option to completely erase the device to which it is being installed which does the same thing that you are looking to achieve.

DO NOT DO THIS if any of the "disks" is mounted, or swapped on. Check with cat /etc/mtab or cat /proc/mounts.

This is an BPI M5 SBC. I cannot install directly to EMMC. The boot up sequence for this board is, first it looks for an OS on the EMMC and only if that fails it tries to get it from SDcard.
